# DHCP table in Debian

Tags: debian, dhcp

How to view all assigned ip addresses on a Debian DHCP server?

It is usually easy to do on a standalone router through a web interface. How to do it with dhcpd in Debian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Debian you have a choice among serveral DHCP servers.  I've used `udhcpd` and `isc-dhcp-server` before.  You are likely using `isc-dhcp-server`.  It records its leases in `/var/lib/dhcpd.leases`.

Newer leases are appended to this file, so look towards the bottom for recently given leases.  Old leases aren't cleaned out until the file reaches some threshold (I don't know what it is off the top of my head).

Comment: Also, it is possible to find **dhcpd.leases** in /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases.

Answer (score 2):

My home debian server uses [dnsmasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) which stores it's leases in
`/var/lib/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.leases`

Comment: On my Debian 9 (stretch) server, file is located at: `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`. Dnsmasq version 2.76.